# ¿Cómo puedo acceder al texto de un InputField en Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

Estoy intentando crear un videojuego en el cual haya un "terminal" con el cual hacer comandos cómo ls, nano etc.

No sé casi nada de entrada de texto en Unity, por ello lo primero que quiero hacer es conseguir el valor que entres por el teclado mediante un input, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.
Pensaba que el código sería el siguiente:

```
   public InputField entrada_txt;

   string txt;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    txt = entrada_txt.text;
    
}``
```

He puesto un `Debug.Log(txt);` para que me muestre el contenido que escribo en el InputField (Y así asegurarme de que tengo el valor), pero no me muestra nada.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado el problema, resulta que al asignar el valor en el void Start, le asignaba un valor vacío y al ejecutar el Debug.Log no assignaba el texto.